# IPhone - Can I use same name again once application validity over on iTunesConnect?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect, mobile-application

I have created one application on iTunesConnect but, before I submit my application on AppStore Application validity was over.

Can I Use the same name to create the new application on iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this question: [App Name Expiry on iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518141/app-name-expiry-on-itunes-connect)

Your app name will be able to be used by another developer and you cannot reuse the app name.