# Remove an app that hasn't been published on the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've created a testing app on iTunes Connect. The status of the app is "Waiting for Upload". Now I want to delete this app. How can I do it? Please see the image  for details. [image]

Comment: Can you clarify what the goal is ? Do you want to reject the binary ? make changes ? or is the project just dead and you want to remove all traces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave it alone.  If you don't submit a binary within 6 months, it will be [deleted by Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518141/app-name-expiry-on-itunes-connect)

Comment: But if you do submit a binary, then you cannot ever remove it. The 6 months is nil as soon as you upload it and developer reject it.

Comment: True, OP did not mention if he's previously submitted binaries before.

Comment: I'm wondering if they will patch that 'bug'. Some circumstances require longer than 6 months of dev time. If you upload a dummy binary and reject it, you just bought all the time you want.

Comment: Just because you are developing something doesn't mean you get to preclude others from using the name.  Unless you have a registered trademark, in which case you can inform Apple and have the other app removed anyway.  So "development sometimes takes more than 6 months" is a moot point I think.  I developed several apps for 18 months, and didn't register the name until right before I released ;).

Comment: Very true, however it takes about 8-9 months to get a trademark. So if you have an app idea and it's a genuinely new/unique name, it's wise to create the app name and secure it for brand protection.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove it. To remove an app, it has to be approved one time. I also have a few Waiting for Upload apps that I would like to remove, but you just can't.

Comment: That's bad. I'm curious about why Apple sets this strange policy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

You can edit the MetaData to wait for your final approval to post the app for sale (instead of as soon as it is approved), then reject it before it ever goes live.

Comment: He doesn't want to submit the app though in the first place.

Comment: I know... but this would allow him/her to delete it before it ever goes live.

Comment: Problem is there should/needs to be a way to not have to get an app approved; in certain circumstances it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove it. To remove an app, you have to wait unto 6 months, it will be deleted by Apple

Answer (score 0):

There is always the option of contacting Apple directly.  In the past I've had the misconception that Apple is a black box and can't be contacted for help but I've worked with two clients in the last year who got direct help from the Developer account and iTunes connect folks.  There is an often unused and overlooked perk of your developer account membership where you can reach out directly to Apple developers to ask for their help in solving a problem (I think you get 5 free per year).

Answer (score 0):

Set price to free, save, then in "Availability" section you can check "remove from sale" and hit save.

[image: Steps]